# Ubuntu 10.04 - Do I need to install Audio Drivers for ASROCK E350M1?

Tags: drivers

I just successfully installed the graphics driver on my  ASROCK E350M1 -THANKS Daniel!- and now I am trying to determine if there is any need to install an audio driver. Audio is fine, I just don't know if it should be better. (I have installed the restricted codecs.)

This is the description of my audio (from ASRock):

```
7.1 CH HD Audio with Content Protection  
(Realtek ALC892 Audio Codec) - Premium Blu-ray audio support.
```

I was not able to locate any Linux drivers on the Realtek or The ASRock site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If it works, don't try to fix it.

A lot of people assume they need a driver for everything (because that has been the truth for almost every piece of hardware in Windows for a long time) but the out-of-the-box drivers in the Kernel for audio and networking are, with a few exceptions, the best option.

Is there a reason you think it should be better?

Comment: Thanks Oli for the reply. The audio works fine, I just assumed that since drivers were supplied with the motherboard, I needed to install some additional drivers. Thanks. I will leave my audio as it is. Thanks again!